# Is there any hook available to override variation regular price at a core level?

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have encountered a situation where I have a variable product with a single variation. However, the Regular price box is empty. I need to override the regular price when it is empty.

Upon more investigating the WooCommerce core files, I discovered that if WooCommerce cannot find a regular price, the variation is not visible, resulting in the message "This product is currently out of stock and unavailable."

I found a filter called `woocommerce_variation_is_visible` that allows me to display the variation but not the price. Unfortunately, I am still unable to add it to the cart.

Further debugging led me to the class `WC_Data_Store_WP`, which retrieves data from the database. I attempted to override the `_price` key value using the filter `apply_filters("woocommerce_data_store_wp_{$this->meta_type}_read_meta", $meta_data, $object, $this);`. However, the filter variable `$meta_data` only contains meta with keys that do not start with `_`, preventing me from accessing the `_price` key.

I am still exploring the WooCommerce core files for a solution to "override variation regular price at the core level".

So far, I have tried the following filters:

1. `woocommerce_variation_is_visible` - This filter allows me to display the variation but not the price.
2. `woocommerce_product_variation_get_price` - Although a dynamic hook, it only works in the `view` context.
3. `woocommerce_data_store_wp_post_read_meta` - Another dynamic hook, but it only works if the meta keys do not start with `_`. In my case, the meta key is `_price`.

I also attempted to extend the `WC_Product` class and override the `get_price` function, but this approach only works for simple products.

If anyone has any ideas or solutions to assist me in changing the "override variation regular price at the core level", I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

**UPDATE**

I am able to display and override price using these below hooks

```
function override_variation_regular_price( $price, $variation ) {
    // Modify the regular price as needed
    $new_regular_price = 50; // Set your desired regular price here

    return $new_regular_price;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_prices_price', 'override_variation_regular_price', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_prices_regular_price', 'override_variation_regular_price', 10, 2 );
```

and

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_visible', 'show_variation_without_price', 10, 2 );
function show_variation_without_price( $visible, $variation_id ) {
    $variation = wc_get_product( $variation_id );
    // Check if the variation regular price is empty or not set
    if ( empty( $variation->get_regular_price() ) ) {
        $visible = true;
    }
    return $visible;
}
```

But it does not allow adding to the cart. and show's this message `Sorry, this product is unavailable. Please choose a different combination.`

**I am still exploring**

Answer (score 0):

**I found the solution.** I was able to do this using the below filters.

This hook allows visible variation in product price form even price is empty.

```
function show_variation_without_price( $visible, $variation_id ) {
    $variation = wc_get_product( $variation_id );
    // Check if the variation regular price is empty or not set
    if ( $variation->is_type( 'variation' ) && empty( $variation->get_regular_price() ) ) {
        $visible = true;
    }
    return $visible;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_visible', 'show_variation_without_price', 10, 2 );
```

This hook allows for visible variation of product purchasable even price is empty. default if price is empty then woocommerce disable add to cart button.

```
function override_is_purchasable( $purchasable, $product ) {
    if ( $product->is_type( 'variation' ) && empty( $product->get_price() ) ) {
        $purchasable = true;
    }
    return $purchasable;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_purchasable', 'override_is_purchasable', 10, 2 );
```

This hook allows to override regular price.

```
function override_variation_regular_price( $price, $variation ) {
    if ( is_product() && $variation->is_type( 'variable' ) && empty( $price ) ) {
        // Modify the regular price as needed
        $new_regular_price = 0; // Set your desired regular price here
    }    
    return $new_regular_price;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_prices_price', 'override_variation_regular_price', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_prices_regular_price', 'override_variation_regular_price', 10, 2 );
```

This hook overrides the price at the cart level.

```
function override_cart_item_price( $cart ) {

    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

        // Check if the product price is empty
        if ( empty( $cart_item['data']->get_price() ) ) {

            $product_id = $cart_item['data']->get_id(); // For version 3 or more

            $new_price = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'new_price', true  );
            
            // Update the cart item price
            $cart_item['data']->set_price( $new_price );
            
        }
    }
    
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'override_cart_item_price', 99, 1 );
```